# How to exclude posts by post ID in this custom ads script?

Tags: php, wordpress, ads

So while searching for a solution to my problem I stumbled upon this code, courtesy of [Sally CJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9217760/sally-cj), but I don't know how to contact him because I'm a new user and can't comment in the thread. 
So I thought maybe some of you or Sally himself, can help me out with excluding some of my posts by "post id" from this script.

```js
function prefix_insert_after_paragraph2( $ads, $content ) {
    if ( ! is_array( $ads ) ) {
        return $content;
    }

    $closing_p = '</p>';
    $paragraphs = explode( $closing_p, $content );

    foreach ($paragraphs as $index => $paragraph) {
        if ( trim( $paragraph ) ) {
            $paragraphs[$index] .= $closing_p;
        }

        $n = $index + 1;
        if ( isset( $ads[ $n ] ) ) {
            $paragraphs[$index] .= $ads[ $n ];
        }
    }

    return implode( '', $paragraphs );
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'prefix_insert_post_ads' );
function prefix_insert_post_ads( $content ) {
    if ( is_single() && ! is_admin() ) {
        $content = prefix_insert_after_paragraph2( array(
            // The format is: '{PARAGRAPH_NUMBER}' => 'AD_CODE',
            '1' => '<div>Ad code after FIRST paragraph goes here</div>',
            '2' => '<div>Ad code after SECOND paragraph goes here</div>',
        ), $content );
    }

    return $content;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
function prefix_insert_post_ads( $content ) {
    global $post;

    $excluded_ids = array(5, 6, 7, 8);
    if (in_array($post->ID, $excluded_ids)) {
       return $content;
    }

    if ( is_single() && ! is_admin() ) {
        $content = prefix_insert_after_paragraph2( array(
            // The format is: '{PARAGRAPH_NUMBER}' => 'AD_CODE',
            '1' => '<div>Ad code after FIRST paragraph goes here</div>',
            '2' => '<div>Ad code after SECOND paragraph goes here</div>',
        ), $content );
    }

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Just tried it. It removes all the content from the excluded posts.

Comment: Works great now!
Thanks for your quick answer and edit :)